# How to access the express request in NextJS from other functions?

Tags: next.js

I am used with PHP and Symfony or Laravel frameworks in which you could easily get the current request with `request()` and do some actions on it, like getting user-agent, referrer etc and enriching the log context.

I want to do the same thing in NextJS 12.0.

I have a logger class and want to enrich my logs with the requestUrl, referrer, userAgent but can't find a way to access the current express request.

Normally there is no request existing during `getStaticProps`, but for `getServerSideProps` such request should exist and I want to use it also in some `http custom middleware` to attach the original request correlation id to the call.

Is there such a way to do it, like just for example `globals.next.request` or whatever or calling a function and next returns the current request or null if no request exists.